# knockout.js assign observable in data-binding declaration

Tags: javascript, data-binding, mvvm, knockout-2.0

Is it possible to set the *showErrorConsole* observable through the data-binding declaration like below? This bomb's out with "*k.apply is not a function*". I know I could use an inline functions here but that just doesn't feel right and is a lot more typing.

**HTML:**

```
<div data-bind="event: { mouseover: showErrorConsole(true) }" ></div>
<div id="devConsole" data-bind="visible: showErrorConsole">
        <div><button data-bind="click: showErrorConsole(false)">X</button></div>
</div>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
AjaxErrorsModel = (function () {
    function Constructor() {
        var self = this;
        self.errors = ko.observableArray();
        self.hasErrors = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.errors().length > 0;
        }, self);
        self.showErrorConsole = ko.observable(false);
    };
    return Constructor;
})();
```

Comment: I was surprised you couldn't set an observable property through the data-bind as well and ended up going with the anonymous function.  It seems like such a basic thing to include - I'm curious why the Knockout authors left it out.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a neat KO trick to let you do this, but the simplest way would be to just add this to your constructor function:

```
self.showErrorConsoleIsFalse = function() {
    self.showErrorConsole(false);
};
```

And then:

```
<button data-bind="click: showErrorConsoleIsFalse">
```

Or if you wanted the mouseover event, it would be the same idea:

```
self.showErrorConsoleIsTrue = function() {
    self.showErrorConsole(true);
};

<div data-bind="event: { mouseover: showErrorConsoleIsTrue }" ></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

And of course there's nothing stopping you from managing these events from jQuery:

```
<div class="showConsole" ></div>

$(".showConsole").hover(function() {
    yourViewModel.showErrorConsole(true);
}, function() {
    yourViewMode.showErrorConsole(false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. After looking at the options I went for the anonymous inline function after all. It wasn't what I wanted but out of the options available it suited my tastes the best. Adding additional "setter" methods in the view model for each property that could be switched on or off just seemed like it would pollute the VM too much.